# Import Python module components from two directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm using Python 3, but with a few small changes I think this applies to Python 2 as well.

I have a project with some plain Python module files, and some shared object libraries which have to be built from source.

The project repo looks like this:

```
python/
    example/
        foo.py
src/
    bar.c

build/ # compiled, not checked in
    python/
        example/
            bar.so
```

Some of the plain Python modules are useful on their own, so I set `PYTHONPATH=python` and then I can `import example.foo`.  Sometimes I want to `import example.bar`, in which case I build `bar.so`.

But now I have a problem because `PYTHONPATH=python:build/python` does not work, because it seems that once Python finds `python/example` it won't look at `build/python/example`.

I would like to be able to tell Python that this module has components in two directories, and if an import fails in one it should look in the other.  Is this possible, or do you have another suggestion?  I am trying to avoid creating a pile of symlinks like this:

```
build/python/example/foo.py -> ../../../python/foo.py
```

Comment: Maybe you can append these paths to `sys.path`?

Comment: Perhaps change the order of the paths in PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: `sys.path` does exactly the same thing as `PYTHONPATH` here.  It doesn't help...I tried just now.

Comment: @HoriaComan: Sure, I can change the order.  Then I can `import bar` and not `import foo`.  I can never get both to work at once.

Comment: I think I ran into the same problem some time ago as well, in a similar setup. I don't think it can be solved because Python expects a module to only exist in one place, whereas you're asking it to exist in two places. In my case, because I was dealing with auto generated code, I just added a wrapper module for that code. You could perhaps add a build/python/native package, which contains all the compiled stuff, and then import it as native.example.bar. You could then add a stub module in Python, which just loads the native thing and exports the names, so people can still use example.bar